# minimal polynomial of a matrix B given minimal polynomial of $B^2$

Tags: jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

If we are given a minimal polynomial for a matrix $B^2$ can we deduce the minimal polynomial for $B$ $?$

**Example:**

if the minimal polynomial for $B^2$ is $m(\lambda) = \lambda^4$ then can we deduce the minimal polynomial for $B$ is $m(\lambda) = \lambda^8$

**Edit**

From my example would I be able to deduce $B$ has a Jordan normal form consisting of an $8\times8$ block with eigenvalue $0$

Comment: Not following.  If $m(B^2)=0$ then $B^8=0$ so $B=0$.  Thus the minimal polynomial for both $B,B^2$ is just $x$.

Comment: As another example, $\left( \sqrt 2 +1\right)^2$ has minimal polynomial $x^2-6x+1$ while $\sqrt 2 +1$ has minimal polynomial $x^2-2x-1$. Hard to see a terribly suggestive pattern there.

Comment: Certainly if $m(B^2) =0$ then $B$ is a root of $m(x^2)$, hence it is a *multiple* of the minimal polynomial of $B$.

Comment: @lulu I'm trying to use it to find the Jordan form of the Matrix $B$, so I don't follow how you can deduce B = 0 in your first example

Comment: @lulu However, $x^2-2x-1$ is a factor of $(x^2)^2-6x^2+1$. In fact, if the minimal polynomial of $B$ is $f(x)$ and that of $B^2$ is $g(x)$, then $f(x)$ will always be a factor of $g(x^2)$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak  Yes, that is certainly true.

Comment: @Scosh_lr  Sorry, I was thinking in the context of algebraic numbers.  Yes, for matrices we can't deduce that $B=0$ from $B^8=0$.

Comment: @berci thanks for your answer, does this mean I can then evaluate the Jordan normal form of $B$ according to the edit ?